# Program for compacting other given code

Tags: python, parsing, compression

I've just finished a small function that will reduce the size of code as much as possible without breaking anything. Obviously it makes everything a bit unreadable so it's not really for cleaning the code, more for if you want to send something but make it awkward for people to edit.

Basically, on the highest level it'll attempt to remove as many spaces and group as many lines together as possible without causing syntax errors with the output code. If there's anything I missed let me know.

I also tried to make it easy to change all the parts if needed, so for example you're not just limited to `"` and `'` to define what text is (you may want some other values to not get edited) and so on.

Anyway, I tested it on one bit of code I had that was 170,000 characters and 3500 lines. It reduced the number of characters down to 100,000 and knocked it down to 1200 lines.

```
import operator
def compactCode(input='',groupMaxSpaces=None,changeIndents=4,indentLevel=4,**kwargs):

    #Check that grouping is not disabled, and set to 50 if it is not a number
    if groupMaxSpaces not in (False, None) and type(groupMaxSpaces) not in (int, float): 
        groupMaxSpaces=50

    #Auto set variables to the best efficiency if 'max' is given
    try:
        maxEfficiency=kwargs["max"]
    except:
        pass
    else:
        if maxEfficiency:
            groupMaxSpaces=-1
            changeIndents=1

    #If text should also be affected
    ignoreText = False
    try:
        ignoreText=kwargs["ignoreText"]
    except:
        pass

    #Remove all triple quoted comments
    input=input.replace('"""',"'''").split("'''");input=''.join(input[::2]);

    possibleSuffixes=list("( :")
    #Conditions that may have their contents on the same line
    groupableNames=set(i+j for i in ('if','else','elif','try','except','finally','for','with','while') for j in possibleSuffixes)
    #Conditions which can't be moved up a line
    fixedNames={x:len(x) for x in set(i+j for i in ('class','def') for j in possibleSuffixes)|groupableNames|{'@staticmethod','@classmethod'}}

    input = input.replace('\\','\\\\').replace('\r\n','\\r\\n')
    removeSpace=list('+-*/=!<>%,.()[]{}:')        #These items will have all spaces next to them removed
    inLineTextMarker=";txt.{};"
    textSymbols=["'",'"']        #Add to this to preserve text if text is defined by anything other than quotation marks and speech marks
    if ignoreText: 
        removeSpace+=textSymbols
        textSymbols=[]
    indentMultiplier=float(changeIndents)/indentLevel
    outputList=[]

    for line in str(input).split('\n')+[';endoflist;']:

        #Remove comments
        line=line.split("#")[0]

        #Replace text as to avoid it being affected
        textStorage={}
        lastSymbolFail=None

        #Loop until all text is replaced
        while True:

            #Find the first symbol
            symbolOccurrances={}
            for symbol in textSymbols:
                placeOfOccurrance = line.find(symbol)
                #Only add to dictionary if there is more than one symbol
                if placeOfOccurrance >= 0 and line.count(symbol)>1:
                    symbolOccurrances[symbol]=placeOfOccurrance

            #Get the first occurance, or break loop if there is none
            try:
                symbol=sorted(symbolOccurrances.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0][0]
            except:
                break
            textStorage[symbol]=[]

            #Replace the text so it won't be cut down later
            while symbol in line:
                splitByText=line.split(symbol,1)
                line=splitByText[0]+inLineTextMarker
                if symbol in splitByText[1]:
                    textSplit=splitByText[1].split(symbol,1)
                    line+=textSplit[1]
                    textStorage[symbol].append(textSplit[0])
                else:
                    line+=splitByText[1]
                    break
            line=line.replace(inLineTextMarker,inLineTextMarker.format(ord(symbol)))

        #Remove double spaces
        stripLine=line.lstrip(' ')
        leadingSpace=int((len(line)-len(stripLine))*indentMultiplier)
        while '  ' in stripLine:
            stripLine=stripLine.replace('  ',' ')

        if stripLine:

            #Remove unnecessary spaces
            for i in removeSpace:
                stripLine=stripLine.replace(' '+i,i).replace(i+' ',i)

            #Replace the text markers with the actual text again
            while True:
                resultsExist={symbol:True for symbol in textSymbols}
                for symbol in textSymbols:
                    currentTextMarker=inLineTextMarker.format(ord(symbol))
                    while currentTextMarker in stripLine:
                        stripLine=stripLine.replace(currentTextMarker,symbol+textStorage[symbol].pop(0)+symbol,1)
                    if currentTextMarker not in stripLine:
                        resultsExist[symbol]=False
                if not any(x in stripLine for x in (inLineTextMarker.format(ord(symbol)) for symbol in textSymbols)):
                    break

            #Group together lines
            if groupMaxSpaces:
                lastLine=None
                try:
                    lastLine = outputList[-1]
                except:
                    pass
                if lastLine and stripLine!=';endoflist;':
                    lastLineLength = len(lastLine)
                    lastLineStripped = lastLine.lstrip()
                    lastLineStrippedLength = len(lastLineStripped)
                    lastIndent = lastLineLength-lastLineStrippedLength
                    lastLength = lastLineStrippedLength
                    #Make sure the last space is of the same indent, and doesn't mark the start of a loop
                    if leadingSpace == lastIndent:
                        if lastLineStrippedLength+len(stripLine)<groupMaxSpaces or groupMaxSpaces<0:
                            if all(x not in stripLine[:y] for x, y in fixedNames.iteritems()):
                                stripLine=lastLineStripped+';'+stripLine
                                outputList.pop(-1)

                #Group to the conditional statements
                oneLineAgo,twoLinesAgo=None,None
                try:
                    twoLinesAgo,oneLineAgo=outputList[-2:]
                except:
                    pass
                if oneLineAgo and twoLinesAgo:
                    oneLineAgoStrip=oneLineAgo.lstrip()
                    twoLinesAgoStrip=twoLinesAgo.lstrip()
                    oneLineAgoIndentLevel = len(oneLineAgo)-len(oneLineAgoStrip)
                    #Check the current indent is less than the last line, and the last line indent is greater than the 2nd last line
                    if leadingSpace<oneLineAgoIndentLevel:
                        if int(oneLineAgoIndentLevel-indentLevel*indentMultiplier)==len(twoLinesAgo)-len(twoLinesAgoStrip):
                            #Make sure 2 lines ago was a statement, but the latest line wasn't
                            if any(x in twoLinesAgoStrip[:7] for x in groupableNames) and all(x not in oneLineAgoStrip[:7] for x in groupableNames):
                                outputList[-2] = twoLinesAgo+oneLineAgoStrip
                                outputList.pop(-1)

            #Add the indent and repeat
            line=' '*leadingSpace+stripLine
            outputList.append(line.rstrip())

    return '\r\n'.join(outputList[:-1])
```

Here's an example of how it works:

Messy input code:

```
'''
Some example code
'''
print "Testing  "+  ( str( 1234 ) + '3' )*2
b = 7
c = 46
print ( b + c )/3

def myFunction( x ):

    #Just a function
    outputList = []
    for i in range( x ):
        outputList.append( i % 10 )

    return outputList

print myFunction( b )
```

Basic:

```
>>>compactCode(input)

print "Testing  "+(str(1234)+'3')*2
b=7
c=46
print(b+c)/3
def myFunction(x):
    outputList=[]
    for i in range(x):
        outputList.append(i%10)
    return outputList
print myFunction(b)
```

With line grouping (the -1 means lines can be any length, otherwise you pick a maximum number):

```
>>>compactCode(input,-1)

print "Testing  "+(str(1234)+'3')*2;b=7;c=46;print(b+c)/3
def myFunction(x):
    outputList=[]
    for i in range(x):outputList.append(i%10)
    return outputList
print myFunction(b)
```

With reduced indents but no line grouping:

```
>>>compactCode(input,0,1)

print "Testing  "+(str(1234)+'3')*2
b=7
c=46
print(b+c)/3
def myFunction(x):
 outputList=[]
 for i in range(x):
  outputList.append(i%10)
 return outputList
print myFunction(b)
```

To avoid messing up print statements and stuff, the text will never be edited unless `ignoreText` is passed as True. Also passing `max` as True will automatically set the lines to infinite length and set all the indents to 1.

For a larger scale example with the code I was using. [Here's the original](http://pastebin.com/VaWTSZH3), and [here's the reduced version](http://pastebin.com/LyzFdpax).

The one thing I didn't use in the examples was `indentLevel`. It's just in case the code has something other than 4 spaces per indent.

Comment: See https://github.com/gareth-rees/minipy

Comment: Ah nice, I guessed there might have been something out there but I never managed to find anything

Comment: For the record, I just tried it out. Without renaming variables it was a tiny bit longer (since I removed the comments and that doesn't), however when I tried to let it rename variables, it shot up to 650k characters from the original 170k :p

Comment: What was your test case? Trying pastebin.com/VaWTSZH3, I find that `minipy` shrinks it from 170k to 108k, and with `--rename` down to 83k. (Also, `minipy` always removes comments.) I'd be grateful if you could [open an issue](https://github.com/gareth-rees/minipy/issues/new) with all the relevant details (Python version, operating system etc.) so I can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Ah nice, didn't realise you made it, and it was just a mistake on my part. I'd passed rename slightly wrong in `minify` :)  The reduce part is really cool though, if you don't mind me asking, how do you detect what is a variable, and which letters are already taken?

Comment: Names are found by walking over the abstract syntax tree in the [`FindNames` class](https://github.com/gareth-rees/minipy/blob/master/minipy.py#L912). The mapping from original names to minified names is constructed in [`rename_ast`](https://github.com/gareth-rees/minipy/blob/master/minipy.py#L982).

Comment: Thanks, that looks a bit above my level but I kinda half understand what you're doing haha. Also noticed something you may have overlooked. There's a lot of repeated functions in the output such as `with b.rowColumnLayout(...` that could be all assigned to one variable

Comment: `minipy` can't be sure that `b.rowColumnLayout` is idempotent — it could be a property that has a side effect, or which returns a different result each time it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, stick to PEP 8.

- Spacing
- `snake_case`
- Line lengths (more than 80 is OK, but 149 is too much)

Don't use `kwargs` for optional arguments.

You do:

```
# Check that grouping is not disabled, and set to 50 if it is not a number
if group_max_spaces not in (False, None) and type(group_max_spaces) not in (int, float): 
    group_max_spaces=50
```

This is bad in several ways:

- `0 == False`, so your code conflates the two in several places
- You ignore type errors
- You treat `None` and `False` the same
- `group_max_spaces` has *another* meaning when negative
- There is no documentation!

Instead, I suggest a smaller mapping:

- If `None`, there is no maximum
- Otherwise, the maximum is the integer given
- Default is `0`, for no grouping (not a special case, just a low number)

The check given can be discarded.

Your next check now looks much simpler, currently as

```
if max:
    group_max_spaces = None
    change_indents = 1
```

This is unfortunate; this argument overrides the others. I would personally instead create a *separate* convenience function:

```
def compact_code_max(input='', *args, **kwargs):
    return compact_code(input, None, 1, *args, **kwargs)
```

This means there's no worry about conflicting arguments, like passing `group_max_spaces=100` and `max` at the same time.

You have

```
input=input.replace('"""',"'''").split("'''");input=''.join(input[::2]);
```

Honestly, this looks like it's been passed through your own function. Split it up (and remove that trailing semicolon)! Add spacing.

Now, this isn't correct either. Not all tripple quoted strings are doc comments. What about

```
description = """
MyFoo

Usage:
    ./my_foo.py --help
    ./my_foo.py eat <food>
    ./my_foo.py throw (chair|up)
"""

print description
```

This compresses to

```
description=
print description
```

!

Also this breaks for something like

```
def foo():
    """
    Here is an example:

        foo('''bar
        bash''')
    """
    ...
```

This compresses to

```
def foo():
    bar
        bash
    ...
```

Oops!

There is no simple way of removing this safely, although AST introspection helps. I suggest just not doing this. However, your code seems to crash inside such strings, so this is no good either.

As such, you really should be doing this through an AST and proper parsing.

You do

```
possible_suffixes = list("( :")
```

It seems simpler to just

```
possible_suffixes = ["(", " ", ":"]
```

You only loop over it, though, so just loop over the string:

```
possible_suffixes = "( :"
```

I also think the prefix `possible_` is redundant.

You have

```
groupable_names = set(i + j for i in ('if','else','elif','try','except','finally','for','with','while') for j in suffixes)
```

The keywords here should be on a separate line and you should use a set comprehension:

```
block_opening_keywords = 'if', 'else', 'elif', 'try', 'except', 'finally', 'for', 'with', 'while'
groupable_names = {i + j for i in block_opening_keywords for j in suffixes}
```

Personally this deprecates the comment which is less explanatory.

You then have

```
# Conditions which can't be moved up a line
fixed_names = {x: len(x) for x in {i + j for i in ('class', 'def') for j in suffixes} | groupable_names | {'@staticmethod', '@classmethod'}}
```

Split it up!

```
# Conditions which can't be moved up a line
fixed_names  = {i + j for i in ('class', 'def') for j in suffixes}
fixed_names |= groupable_names
fixed_names |= {'@staticmethod', '@classmethod'}

fixed_names = {x: len(x) for x in fixed_names}
```

The cost of caling `len` is low (constant time lookup of a C attribute), so I'd remove that last line and just call `len` when need be.

You're mixing `'` and `"` somewhat haphazardly; stick to one. You seem to be using `'` more, so I'll adjust others to that.

Now, I'm confused about what this actually does. Why separate out `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod`, as opposed to all other `@decorator` calls?

---

Now, that's enough analysis of the code for now. Howver, there are some bugs. Here's one.

```
if False: pass
print(1)
```

gets converted to

```
if False:pass;print(1)
```

Really I think this strategy of string replacement is too hard to get right. Look at a proper AST transformer like given in the comments.

Comment: Sorry it took a while, but thanks so much for the feedback, it's been really useful reading through lol. I've started trying to document functions and classes now, and breaking up the longer lines (if they break up nicely - if it's a long string I'll leave it). The `len` part is needed later on to check only the start of the string, since otherwise, if I had `print "if"`, it could still detect it as an `if`. With mixing `'` and `"`, it was to try detect which was first, so it wouldn't affect the other one if it occured in a string.

Comment: With the bugs, thanks for pointing them out, I hadn't realised not all triple quoted bits were just comments, and likewise, I hadn't thought of putting `'''` inside `"""` or vice versa. With pass, I think it'd solve that by adding it to `fixedNames` (I forgot about it to be fair), plus I've only ever seen `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` so the others didn't cross my mind, all I'd need to do is make sure anything starting with `@` doesn't get moved :)    As to the first point you made, the mixed capitals seems ok with PEP8, and I think they look a bit neater than underscores

Comment: @Peter For the `len` part, you don't need it. Just call `len` in the `all`. In fact, you can just do `all(not strip_line.startswith(x) for x in fixed_names)`. That's the only place you'd use the `len`.  // "With pass, I think it'd solve that by adding it to `fixedNames`" → That doesn't solve it; it could be any other single statement instead. // "mixed capitals seems ok with PEP8" → PEP 8 says "mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility." I'm certain that the convention is `snake_case`.

Comment: Ahh nice one, I wasn't aware of `.startswith()`, that looks an awful lot more efficient to use. As to the mixed capitals, I think me using them comes from doing all the python inside Maya (and I'd missed the bit that said it's only for backwards compatibility). All the Maya commands are things like, `pm.polyAverageVertex`, `pm.defaultNavigation` etc, and I've only recently branched out into doing non-Maya things with python. What would your suggestion on that be then, bearing in mind I'll usually finish non Maya code like this, but then build a UI in Maya to make it easier to use?

Comment: @Peter In situations like that, it's pretty much whatever you think works best. Personally I would use `camelCase` when extending Maya (eg. superclasses or wrappers of their stuff) and use `snake_case` elsewhere but I've never seen Maya, never mind used it.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the tips. For the record, Maya is a 3D program, so instead of building upon the classes or whatever, you use the inbuilt functions mixed with normal python to do the program specific things. I've just been building the user interfaces inside it because they're an awful lot more easy to do than from what I've seen of tkinter :)